# Applying group-relative transforms to object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to move a `THREE.Object3D` in 3D space relative to the viewport's 2D x/y. In `moveChar()` some calculations are applied using `THREE.Quaternion` and it works in successfully moving the entire `game` (THREE.Group) on the correct plane, but I'm trying to move `cha` instead.

I've tried swapping variables between each `THREE.Object3D`, applying quats and inverse quats to different things, and a whole slew of other stuff. I'm not as advanced in math as I'd like to be, so please bear with me.

main.js

```
let container;
let camera; 
let controls;
let game;
let renderer;
let scene;

function init() {
    container = document.querySelector('#scene-container');
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const fov = 35;
    const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 100;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);

    game = new THREE.Group();
    scene.add(game);
    controls = new THREE.ObjectControls(camera, container, game);

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

    var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    game.add(mesh1);
    //cha stands for character
    var cha = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    cha.position.set(0,1,0);
    game.add(cha);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    });
}

function moveChar(ev) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    var offset = new THREE.Vector3();
    // so camera.up is the orbit axis
    var quat = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(game.up, new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
    var quatInverse = quat.clone().inverse();

    var position = game.position;

    offset.copy(position);

    // rotate offset to "y-axis-is-up" space
    offset.applyQuaternion(quat);

    switch (keyCode) {
        case 68: //d
            offset.x += 1;
            break;
        case 83: //s
            offset.y -= 1;
            break;
        case 65: //a
            offset.x -= 1;
            break;
        case 87: //w
            offset.y += 1;
            break;
    }

    // rotate offset back to "camera-up-vector-is-up" space
    offset.applyQuaternion(quatInverse);

//****** Here is where the group is being transformed ******
    position.add(offset.sub(position));
//    cha.position.add(offset.sub(position));
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", moveChar);

init();
```

When I press WASD the `cha` should move relative to the viewport's 2D x/y. I can succeed in getting it to move, but the translations end up incorrect and it moves around in 3D space unpredictably.

Comment: Try the three.js `misc_controls_orbit.html` example, but set `controls.screenSpacePanning = true;` Panning is with the arrow keys in that example.

Comment: @west So the panning in this example is based on a 2D plane in the 3D world. If you rotate the camera around, the plane that the objects move on does not change. I am looking to rotate objects in 3D and then shift them on a flat plane relative to the viewport or the camera's perspective.

Comment: When `controls.screenSpacePanning` is set to `true`, panning occurs in screen-space.